# How to set formcontrolname to a particular row in the table instead of reflecting entire data table in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular

I want to set the form controller name from ts file through setVale() but when i do that,it set to all rows in the table ,please help me

> HTML PAGE

```
       <ng-container matColumnDef="gross">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>GROSS</mat-header-cell>
       <!-- <mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale"> {{sale.gross}} </mat-cell> -->
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let sale">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="list-style:none ;">
        <input matInput readonly=true formControlName="gross">
      </mat-form-field>
          <!-- <span *ngIf="sale.isEdit">{{sale.disPer}}</span> -->
        </mat-cell>
     </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="Actions">
                      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                            Actions
                      </mat-header-cell>
                      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                 <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" 
        *ngIf="row.isEdit"  (click)=" showEditButton(row)" color="primary" matTooltip="Edit Bill">
       <mat-icon>create</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" 
   *ngIf="row.isEditMode" (click)=" editBillItems(row)" color="primary" matTooltip="submit Bill">
      <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button  aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon" 
          *ngIf="row.isEditMode1" (click)=" clear()" color="primary" matTooltip="clear Bill">
     <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button color="warn" type="button"*ngIf="row.isEdit" 
     (click)="deleteBillItems(row)" matTooltip="Delete Bill">
     <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                </button>
          </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
```

> TS FILE

```
    findGross(data)
   {
          let qty=this.formGroup.controls.editQuantity.value;
         let unit=data.price;
       let q=data.quantity;
        console.log("qty n unitt"+qty+unit);
         data.gross=qty*unit;
       this.formGroup.controls['gross'].setValue(qty*unit);
   }
```

Anyone please help me i am working on it from past two days, the below pic shows that when add the 
   unit ,it call the function for the gross , and in ths file using setValue the gross is setting to its 
    formcontrolname but at the same time it reflects to other rows too ,how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a model for each row in your form group.
Basically what is happening is you have one Gross model in your formGroup, instead of one for each row. This means all the rows will have the same value.

This page is going to help you a lot: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

I think the thing that is the easiest just now is to generate your form control names with functions based on the index in your for loop (given it's a table).

In your for loop, get the row index using this code:

`<tr *ngFor="let item of items; let row = index"`

The change your inputs to have generate form names, so they each have a unique model.

`<input matInput readonly=true formControlName="{{getGrossFormControlName(row)}}"`

Then in your component code you can have:

`getGrossFormControlName(rowIndex: number): string {
   return 'gross' + rowIndex;
}`

Do the same for the other variables used in template the gross calculation so you get the right calculated value. Otherwise there will just be a single model for each attribute.

Comment: if i am using this method ,how will setValue() function using instance of formGroup